# How to merge two row with two different column size in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to merge "Text" to the other column under the "Picture"

[Reference of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2Jx.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>grid</title>

        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }

            .container {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
            
                display: grid;

                grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 1fr 100px;

                gap: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .container div {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .header {
                grid-column-start: 1;
                grid-column-end: 3;
            }
            .text {
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 4;
                grid-column-start: 2;
                grid-column-end: 3;
            }
        
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
            <div class="pic">Picture</div>
            <div class="text">Text  </div>
        </div>

    
    </body>
</html>
```

This should be the output:

[Should be the output after the problem fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVVhJ.png)

↑↑↑
Use the link above for reference if it is confusing

↑↑↑The output that i want is in the link above i cant paste it here in description because there is an error sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: If you want to text to flow around the `.pic` div, all you need is `.pic {float: left;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer:
It might be easier to not use display grid for this, since you want the reverse L shape. I removed some of your CSS code and got this result, is this slightly close to your desired result?

[image]

Comment: almost like that but i want to connect it on the right side that there should be like reverse L shape

Comment: @Trinity I've edited my post, I wonder if it helps!

Comment: is it possible if I use grid?

Comment: @Trinity I researched a bit on css grids, and I think you may add another "small grid" labeled "Text" under "Picture", if you really want the effect. But that won't display the desired reversed L shape. CSS Grid displays rectangular objects, and I don't know if you can get a reversed L shape with grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the page view you are showing with flex.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="header">Here is your header</div>
      <div style="display: flex">
        <div>
          <img
            src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/realistic-credit-card-design_23-2149126090.jpg"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          Here is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere
          is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is
          lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot
          of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of
          contentHere is lot of contentHere is lot of content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```